# Is a $L^1$-function which is linear near the origin in $L^p$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Suppose you have a function $f$ on $\mathbb{R}$, such that
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} | f(x) | \, \mathrm{d} x < \infty$$
and
$$\int_{-u}^u |f(x)| \, \mathrm{d} x = \mathcal{O}(u)$$
for $u \to 0$.

Is it true that then $f$ is in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ for any $p \geq 1$?

I think the answer is yes, because $f$ doesn't blow up at zero but I'm struggling with a formal proof. 
I've tried to look at the measure $\mu$ defined by $\mu(\mathrm{d}x) = |f(x)| \mathrm{d}x$, exploiting the fact that $\mu(B)<\infty$ for any Borel set on the real line, but didn't suceed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example which can be adapted as required by fiddling a little with the exponents occurring below. Let $I_0=[0,1)$, $I_n=[\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{k^2}, \sum_{k=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{k^2})$, which is of length $1/n^2$. Define $f(x)=1/n^{1/2}$ on the $I_n$'s ($n\ge 1$) and $0$ elsewhere. $f$ is clearly $L^1$ but not $L^p$ if $p\ge 2$. Also, $f\equiv 0$ on $[0,1)$.

Answer (score 2):

Is false.

For each $n\in{\Bbb N}$,

$$f_n(x)=\cases{
        x^{-n/(n+1)} & for $x\in(0,1)$,\cr
        0 & for $x\not\in(0,1)$.\cr
}$$
Is easy to see that $f_n\in L^p$ for $1\le p < (n+1)/n$ and $f_n\not\in L^p$ for $ p\ge(n+1)/n$.

The function

$$f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty{f_n(x-n)\over 2^n||f_n||_{L^1}}$$
is in $L^1\setminus L^p$ for all $p>1$ and is zero near zero.

Comment: Martín-Blas Pérez Pinill Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand your counterexample. $f_n$ is continuous with compact support and thus in L^p for any $p \geq 1$. Furthermore, $\| f_n(x-n) \|_p^p = \int_n^{n+1}(x-n)^{np/(n+1)} \mathrm{d}x = (n+1)/(np) + 1 \leq 2/p + 1$ so that $\| f \|_p < \infty$ for all $p \geq 1$. Am I missing something?

Comment: @herrsimon, $f_n$ isn't continous at $x=1$ and $\| f_n(x-n) \|_p^p = \int_n^{n+1}(x-n)^{np/(n+1)}dx = \int_0^1 t^{np/(n+1)}dt$, divergent for $np/(n+1)\ge 1$.

Comment: Martín-Blas Pérez Pinill (somehow the @name syntax doesn't work with your username): Sorry, I still don't get it, apparently it's too early in the morning here :-) What I meant was piecewiese continuous. Even though I might make a fool out of myself: What exactly do you mean by saying that $\int_0^1 t^{np/(n+1)} \mathrm{d}t$ is divergent for $np/(n+1) \geq 1)$? The integral exists by dominated convergence with the constant function $1$ being an integrable bound (on $(0,1)$), correct? But then every single summand is integrable and due to the factor $1/2^n$ the sum is finite.

Comment: @herrsimon, missign sign in exponent, sorry for the mess.

Comment: Aaaah, I get it :-) So in fact you're moving the blow-ups away from zero, very nice counterexample indeed! Thanks for your help!